# How can I use cross validation in python?

Tags: python, list, cross-validation

I have a big list of data. I want to split this list into training and test lists. I can split it via applying

```
cutoff = int(.7 * len(data_list)) # 70% of the data is used for training
training_list = data_list[:cutoff]
test_list = data_list[cutoff:]
```

But I don't think this is a good strategy to evaluate my tagger. How is it possible to divide my list with this percentage but at different places and get reliable evaluation scores ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is function called `train_test_split()` in `sklearn.model_selection`
Docs : [Train Test Split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

You can find the examples also at the same link.

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> aaa = list(range(20))
>>> aaa
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> train_test_split(aaa, test_size=0.3)
[[7, 14, 2, 1, 5, 13, 3, 8, 9, 17, 15, 0, 10, 16], [11, 6, 4, 19, 12, 18]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and reference